# Script error on Startup , Enthought Canopy

Tags: enthought

I recently installed Canopy on my machine and when I try to start Canopy or Package Manager , I get an error "Your customization startup script failed". The following details come with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\application.py", line 847, in
^execute_start_scripts   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\scripting\script_engine.py", line 116,
in execute   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "<string>",
line 2, in activate_task   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\scripting\recordable.py", line 76, in
_wrapper   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\scripting\script_engine.py", line 195,
in record_call   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\application.py", line 510, in
activate_task   File "<string>", line 2, in get_task   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\scripting\recordable.py", line 76, in
_wrapper   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\scripting\script_engine.py", line 195,
in record_call   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\application.py", line 531, in
get_task   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\app\application.py",
line 439, in create_window   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\ui\tasks\tasks_application.py",
line 205, in create_window
    window.add_task(task)   File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\pyface\tasks\task_window.py", line 182, in add_task
    state.central_pane.create(self.control)   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\plugin\package_manager_task.py", line
94, in create   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\package_manager\package_manager_ui.py",
line 2586, in __init__   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\package_manager\package_manager_service.py",
line 721, in _enstaller_config_default   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\application.py",
line 370, in get_service
    protocol, query, minimize, maximize   File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 77, in get_service
    services = self.get_services(protocol, query, minimize, maximize)   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 114, in get_services
    actual_protocol, name, obj, properties, service_id   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\envisage\service_registry.py", line 258, in _resolve_factory
    obj = obj(**properties)   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\accounts\plugin.py", line 61, in
_create_account_service   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 303,
in __init__   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py",
line 3510, in _init_trait_listeners
    getattr( self, '_init_trait_%s_listener' % data[0] )( name, *data )   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py",
line 3565, in _init_trait_delegate_listener
    self.on_trait_change( notify, name_pattern, target=self )   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py",
line 2814, in on_trait_change
    listener.register( self )   File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py",
line 433, in register
    value = getattr( self, type )( new, name, False )   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\traits\traits_listener.py",
line 701, in _register_simple
    return next.register( getattr( object, name ) )   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 253,
in _preferences_default   File
"build\bdist.win32\egg\canopy\accounts\account_service.py", line 259,
in _enstaller_config_default   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py",
line 299, in from_file
    ret = _create(fp)   File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py",
line 279, in _create
    for k, v in parser.parse(fp.read()).iteritems():   File "C:\Program
Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\enstaller\config.py",
line 99, in parse
    root = ast.parse(s)   File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\ast.py",
line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)   File "<unknown>", line 63
    EPD_auth = 'bGl2aXUucGFudGlsaWUuMjAxMkBudWltLmllOmhROSV1RjJOKmV0cVImekVTZW1CQ2ZiJFoleXhU
                                                                                        ^ SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what is the output of `enpkg --config` from a command prompt?

Comment: enstaller: Error: enstaller crashed (uncaught exception <type 'exceptions.Syntax
Error'>: SyntaxError('EOL while scanning string literal', ('C:\\Users\\lucki_000
\\.enstaller4rc', 63, 88, "EPD_auth = 'bGl2aXUucGFudGlsaWUuMjAxMkBudWltLmllOmhRO
SV1RjJOKmV0cVImekVTZW1CQ2ZiJFoleXhU\n"))).
Please report this on enstaller issue tracker:
    http://github.com/enthought/enstaller/issues
You can get a full traceback by setting the ENSTALLER_DEBUG environment variable

Comment: Hi Jonathan, this is the output you requested

Comment: Hi Jonathan, so can you help me out with this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the authentication is corrupted in `.enstaller4rc`.  Notice the unterminated single-quote at the end of the line starting with `EPD_auth='...`

You can try deleting `c:\\Users\lucki_000\\.enstaller4rc`.  It should be recreated when you log in again through the GUI or if you run `enpkg --userpass` from a `cmd` shell.